# Obter lista de objetos com JPA e Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Gostaria de uma ajuda. Em meu código o método de inserir o objeto no banco está funcionando, no entanto ao tentar obter uma lista dos objetos armazenados no banco, recebo o erro que minha tabela não está mapeada. Abaixo encontra-se as classes, o xml e o log de erros.

**Pessoa.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pessoas")
public class Pessoa {
    private Long id;
    private Integer idade;
    public static String NAME = "name";
    protected SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="pessoas_id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="pessoas_nome")
    public String getNome() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.name.set(nome);
    }

    @Column(name="pessoas_idade")
    public Integer getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(Integer idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
}
```

**PessoaDao.java**

```
public class PessoaDAO {
    private EntityManager manager;
    private EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public PessoaDAO() {

        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("wehave");
        manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void insert(Pessoa pessoa) {
        try {

            manager.persist(pessoa);
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

    public void remove(Pessoa pessoa) {
        try {
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            manager.remove(pessoa);
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

    }

    public List<Pessoa> getList()
    {
        Query query = manager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM pessoas e");
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = query.getResultList();
        return pessoas;
    }

}
```

**Teste.java**

```
public class Teste {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Pessoa p = new Pessoa();

            p.setNome("Gabriel");
            p.setIdade(19);

            Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa();

            p2.setNome("José");
            p2.setIdade(72);

            Pessoa p3 = new Pessoa();

            p3.setNome("Maria");
            p3.setIdade(27);

            Pessoa p4 = new Pessoa();

            p4.setNome("Rodolfo");
            p4.setIdade(16);

            PessoaDAO dao = new PessoaDAO();
            dao.insert(p4);
            dao.insert(p3);
            dao.insert(p2);
            dao.insert(p);

            List<Pessoa> pessoas = dao.getList();

            for (int a=0; a<pessoas.size(); a++)
            {
                System.out.println(pessoas.get(a).getNome());
            }

        }
    }
```

**pesistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com    /xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
<persistence-unit name="wehave" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>model.Pessoa</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/wehavescience" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxx" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**STACKTRACE**

> set 04, 2014 6:50:31 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
>   WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:31 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
>   WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:31 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
>   WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:31 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
>   INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>       name: wehave
>       ...]
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:31 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>   INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:31 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment 
>   INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:31 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
>   INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:32 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager 
>   INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
>   WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
>   INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/wehavescience]
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
>   INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
>   INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
>   INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:33 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect 
>   INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:33 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 
>   INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:34 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
>   INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:34 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
>   INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:34 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
>   INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:34 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata 
>   INFO: HHH000261: Table found: wehavescience.pessoas
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:34 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata 
>   INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [pessoas_idade, pessoas_id, pessoas_nome]
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:34 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata 
>   INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:34 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata 
>   INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
>   set 04, 2014 6:50:34 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
>   INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
>   Hibernate: insert into pessoas (pessoas_idade, pessoas_nome) values (?, ?)
>   Hibernate: insert into pessoas (pessoas_idade, pessoas_nome) values (?, ?)
>   Hibernate: insert into pessoas (pessoas_idade, pessoas_nome) values (?, ?)
>   Hibernate: insert into pessoas (pessoas_idade, pessoas_nome) values (?, ?)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: pessoas is not mapped [from pessoas]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
>       at controller.PessoaDAO.getList(PessoaDAO.java:48)
>       at app.Teste.main(Teste.java:38)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: pessoas is not mapped [from pessoas]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
>       at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
>       ... 2 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: pessoas is not mapped
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:332)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3678)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
>       ... 10 more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não deve usar, na HQL, o nome da sua tabela e sim o nome da classe.
Tente isso:

`Query query = manager.createQuery("FROM Pessoa");`

Se quiser saber mais sobre HQL dê uma olhada aqui: [Capítulo 15. HQL: A Linguagem de Consultas do Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/pt-BR/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: Era isso mesmo... Obrigado!

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado também! rs

Answer (score 1):

Duas coias que notei:
1° - troque no persistence.xml o provider que está usando por este:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

O provider do pacote ejb está depreciado.

2° - no seu método insert() chame primeiro o begin() e depois o persist().

```
public void insert(Pessoa pessoa) {
    try {            
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(pessoa);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        manager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```