# Erro: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate

Tenho esse método:

```
public List<AvaCriterio> getList(){
        List<AvaCriterio> lista = null;
        try{
           Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
           session.beginTransaction();
           lista = (List<AvaCriterio>)session.createQuery("from ava_criterio").list();
           session.getTransaction().commit();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {System.out.println("Erro: "+e.getMessage());}

        return lista;
    }
```

Dá esse erro ao executar:

> fev 07, 2017 5:16:46 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions WARN:
>   SQL Error: 936, SQLState: 42000 Erro: could not extract ResultSet

Onde está o erro?

Comment: Qual banco de dados você está utilizando? Como está o seu arquivo de configuração do Hibernate?

Comment: Oracle, Bom. Ele está salvando e alterando.

Comment: Resolvi com a resposta [desta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31549/obter-lista-de-objetos-com-jpa-e-hibernate) pergunta